# Azure Error when adding custom attribute to Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Trying to add a custom attribute to Azure B2C and getting this error

Tried something simple such as calling it test but still same error

Cannot save user attribute: The B2C service has an internal error. If you created this B2C directory just now, please try again after couple of minutes. If the problem persists, please contact Support (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-support/).
 If you do not have a B2C directory you can refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-get-started/

Anyone seen anything like it

Comment: try now. It is working

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We had a service issue that prevented a few administrators from being able to perform certain administrative actions on their tenant such as creating a new user attribute. The issue was mitigated and resolved at 21:54 UTC on Sept. 7, 2017. Please try again and thanks for reporting.

Comment: Hey I can confirm that deleting and creating new ones is good

Answer (score 0):

Azure fixed this issue , great quick support again guys